# Why there is no unit of energy?

Tags: energy, si-units, metrology

In the SI System (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) there are 7 units, but no unit of energy, though this is surely the fundamental unit of physics.

Yet the Joule is usually referred to as a unit of energy, oddly enough, since its unit (the Planck unit $h$) is defined as the unity of action.

Can you explain why there is no official unit of energy and clarify this apparent mess?

Comment: Planck's constant has dimensions of energy-time (or angular momentum), not energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a unit of energy (the Joule, as you mention), it is just not a *base unit*. You can derive it from base units, for example those for lenght, mass and time. As to why it is not a base unit, try looking at: [Why is energy not an SI base unit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166568/why-is-energy-not-an-si-base-unit)

Comment: How can the Joule be the energy unit, when its basic unit h is the unity of action? When does the transmutation grom h to J takes place?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a physical unit is. h is *not* a unit, but a physical constant (and has dimensions of action, indeed). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measurement